# Changing verification email Microsoft cognitive services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Anyone know how to change the default verification email when subscribing? Its not using my microsoft email and it doesn't give me an option to change it. At least I don't see anywhere.
its this page https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-US/subscriptions

Appreciate the help

For Reference
[Registration Page Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEOZW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I logged in using a social network account and the default email changed. This probably seemed like a rookie issue but it really was a pain. There should be a way to set the email you want your confirmation sent to.